# Proving a differential equation doesn't have a nontrivial periodic solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let's suppose we are given $f=(f_1,f_2): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $C^1$ class with the property:

$$(1)  \ \ \ \forall_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}>0. $$

It is claimed that equation $z'=(x',y')=f(z)$ has no periodic solutions except perhaps constant solutions.

I would welcome **some hint** becouse I can't figure out what exactly the condition $(1)$ gives us?

So far my only attempt to attack the problem was using Lagrange theorem as usually with periodic differentiable functions but I can't connect that with $(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key points:

1. Condition (1) says that the divergence of the vector field $f$ is everywhere positive.
2. If you had a closed curve $\Gamma$ on which  $f$ always points in tangential direction, then the integral of divergence of $f$ over the region bounded by $\Gamma$ would be zero.

This is a special case of the [Bendixson–Dulac theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem).

Comment: Actually I am not shure if I fallow your idea correctyl so allow me to ask you wheather the followin is right: assume $z$ is the solution than let considere the curve $z=(z_2,z_1):[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ (I have to manipulate the order in Green theorem) by which we have $\int \int_D (\frac{\partial{f_1}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{f_2}}{\partial{y}})dxdy=\int_z(-f_2,f_1)ds=\int_a^b(-f_2(z_2(t),f_1(z_1(t)))(z_2'(t),z_1'(t))dt=\int_a^b-f_2(z_2(t))z_2'(t)dt+\int_a^bf_1(z_1(t))z_1'(t)dt=-\int_{z_2(a)}^{z_2(b)}f_2(t)dt+\int_{z_1(a)}^{z_1(b)}f_1(t)dt$ which end the case because $z(a)=z(b)$?

Comment: The case ends when you observe that the vector $(-f_2, f_1)$ is orthogonal to the boundary, hence you have zero inside the integral.

Comment: yes, it is orthogonal to the boundary but why does it implies that the second (?) integral is 0 ?

Comment: Because the dot product of orthogonal vectors is zero.

Comment: you are so right and I am so busted ;) so sorry for my missinterpretation and big thanks !

Comment: How to connect this to no Periodic solution? Can you please tell me....